# A short story about artificial intelligence written by an author from Russia or Poland?

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, stanislaw-lem

I once read an interesting short story about the possibility of a set of intelligent machines creating philosophy. Unfortunately I can't find the book that contains this short story. All I can remember it was an author from the so called Soviet bloc -- someone from the USSR or from Poland. Maybe Stanislaw Lem.

It was a dispute between a philosopher and a computer scientist or a programmer.

Does anybody remember that?

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of Golem XIV by Stanislaw Lem, which is structured around a philosophical lecture by the eponymous superintelligent AI. Golem XIV, has developed consciousness, lost interest in its original military purpose, and become interested in philosophical problems. There really is not a dispute per se between Golem XIV and any human computer scientist, but the book contains a forward, an introduction, and an afterward, written by three (fictional) humans. Whereas authors of the forward and introduction are more interested in the concept of a machine engaging in philosophy, the author of the afterward, Richard Popp, seems genuinely interested in considering the philosophical claims made by Golem XIV.

Comment: Unfortunately not, kind @calmcc !

In the Science Fiction and Fantasy forum, another kind soul indicated the short story Bet, by Vladlen Bakhnov that corresponds more accurately to my recollection. 

You may see the answer at [A short story about artificial intelligence written by an author from Russia or Poland?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275908/a-short-story-about-artificial-intelligence-written-by-an-author-from-russia-or)